# form is submitting instead return false javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test my form for validation. I don't have an .asp or .php file so I was informed I could use action="". My code doesn't seem to function right.On codepen it shows as values being posted. Jsfiddle gives me an error thats a paragraph long. In browser the page just seems to refresh. I have no alerts showing for anything....

what am I doing wrong here?

HTML:

```
<form name="name_form" action="" onsubmit="ValidateFormJS()" method="post">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
    <br> Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="last_name">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function ValidateFormJS() {
    var first = document.forms["name_form"]["first_name"].value;
    var last = document.form["name_form"]["last_name"].value;

    if (first == null || first == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out.");
        return false;
    } else if (last == null || last == "") {
        alert("Last name must be filled out.");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("Form Submitted.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned values from the function are never used.
You forgot `return` before the function call on `onsubmit` event.

```
onsubmit="return ValidateFormJS()"
```

Another problem is that you're using `document.form` to get the value of `last name`. It should be `document.forms`.

The last `else` can be removed.

**Demo**

```js
var form = document.forms["name_form"];

function ValidateFormJS() {
  var first = form["first_name"].value,
    last = form["last_name"].value;

  if (first == null || first == "") {
    alert("First name must be filled out.");
    return false;
  } else if (last == null || last == "") {
    alert("Last name must be filled out.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="name_form" action="" onsubmit="return ValidateFormJS()" method="post">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="first_name">
  <br>Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="last_name">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

in view

```
<form name="name_form" action="" onsubmit="return ValidateFormJS();" method="post">
```

in js code

```
function ValidateFormJS() {
    var first = document.forms["name_form"]["first_name"].value;
    var last = document.form["name_form"]["last_name"].value;

    if (first == null || first == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out.");
        return false;
    } else if (last == null || last == "") {
        alert("Last name must be filled out.");
        return false;
    }

    alert("Form Submitted.");
    return true;
}
```